# Fitting with one common and some different parameters over a series of measurments in python

Tags: python, data-fitting

here is the problem again, i hope now its clear to everybody. 
I have some samples data, lets name those j. For each sample of data, i have a theoretical modell, that i can fit to the data. For the sake of simplicity, lets name the fitting function f(sig1, µ1, sig2, m2). Of course, as the data for each sample is slightly different, i get from each sample a different sig1, µ1, sig2, µ2. And here comes my problem: I need the µ1 to be the same i each measurment, but i don't know it in advance. Of course, i could now fit every sample j, just take e.g. the mean of µ1 and the fit them all again, but that is not the best approximation. So, i want to fit µ1 global for all my measurments at the same time and all my other parameters for each single measurment. 
i hope my question is clear now.

Comment: Post some example code and somebody might be able to understand and help.  Also, "And here comes my problem: I need the µ1 to be the same i each measurment, but i don't know it in advance."  Do you mean that you need µ1 to be the same in each model and you need to decide how to average it across all of your fitting results?

Comment: I dont have helpfull sample code as i have no clou how to start this problem. But yes, you understood it correct. I need µ1 to be the same in each model, but i dont want to get if from averaging, i want to get it from fitting all my samples at once where µ1 is only one parameter but exists more often sigma1_j=1, sigma_j=2, ... (and of course the same for µ2 and sig2)

Comment: Are you fitting a gaussian or something?  It's still hard to understand without something concrete.  If you are not changing anything about your experiment between acquisitions, you could combine all of your data and run your fitting function on that.  Then you can decide what to do with each sample from there.